# Why is Scrapy getting only some results? (302 redirect)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written a Scrapy spider to get contents of articles from a long list of URLs scraped from a Baidu search result.

It works to begin with, but then seems to stop getting content after that - all the rest of the several thousand URLS don't produce anything. It says Scrapy is Redirecting (302) to  these URLs load when I try them, and many have the elements I am trying to grab, but Scrapy is not getting this data.

I've spent hours trying to figure out why... I've tried adjusting the speed of Scrapy making the requests, and tried changing the code for extracting data, but it's still no happening.

Here's the spider code:

```
import json

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "GET"

    def start_requests(self):
        data = []
        urls = []
        with open("/Users/.../PycharmProjects/GT/GT/links1.json") as f:
            for line in f:
                data.append(json.loads(line))

        for line in data:
            url = line['link']
            urls.append(url)

        global idx
        for idx, url in enumerate(urls):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for content in response.css("div.all-con"):
            yield {
                    'time': content.css("div.metadata-info p.time::text").get(),
                    'title': content.css("div.t-container-title h3::text").get(),
                    'text': "".join(content.css("div.l-container p::text").get()),
            }
```

And the links I am crawling look like this (there are ~2500 of them):

```
{"link": "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=g147bb1CGmddvvH2aoAEOqlFbyGcMACQpsc5ByxSZ_tF5hPcNXUdN3J3jP2XVcRDIDC4QFZ4hcqOFVSbshGpuq"}
{"link": "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=ptYcsVZSxMJ2YhLwSZuFjr_6ukftIdhl74589-olFOuqYe9rO-MxZhTLuPnyl55Lk2680r7rE59bEIMn1tHQ6a"}
{"link": "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=RsL4nmPDLYkCZ9KroyogLPgJ1t6ZnBX_N75OHlRLUXH40xJ2-0UfzLU0WtxzHcvOOuZUKtpBgaH0mzeUnSnvCK"}
{"link": "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=sqLCagxjItulhRLgg7hIqIl4HSnG5W9gCotVMEpMVDZtsFFY0cxvA0uVDFwOODlB520qOnLxIwqQ8_owlXmZr_"}
{"link": "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=euJcn2_Y5sbLzHlJKVtxFIiqipqv-THBEO60ZNm3eAKAQ9ccLfZhkmz_2bwltI3aXsFzVv4ZqiT7tGzg6C3vH_"}
{"link": "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=sbzqKKvvB91V1qpTXTsOwUO819odCOZgBIPj9g5xcttDRM_MiINnbQiMjyLhLhMd0ZJLqUqm90_3B9cUADprVk_mUtD5w8cFHQtxRnu5d33"}
{"link": "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=D5sm4ZzHLzO2zPGq-Oyi5_9K2Gp4vYU8DeLOOZ7ENj13te8eQGyyh6ugPCdkBIpgj1q4yi12KuZ5MzE6-iX_ddwpiGdZuvDe7YVSP5kcpPu"}
{"link": "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=B2o8aoFz1MTV6fqxx6puxTHN1PsFBzzkMba5wi0T1-ac_HD5z02qRuzAfsR5__pTuevcv1fGAUdD77M-U0rcIaUth0oHKFl2q-7136AuJ8e"}
{"link": "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=UiIg-ELqdzxPwxW5LrJYbBvQTWTe6nohtf6Mx85FAk2yV3iwIaKX3cI9yjub0AEQ-c3D6G47YsrBJ3h_yk_Sn1Vo3UGgqTcljyO9hJbcaCG"}
{"link": "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=JcKaRn6JAUCEvKhdh9w5jTPvuaUdh6e7mfktNdQmHZzGDmMtwn2rD6Nil0ret_y-IXbufdAucbZc5OTijj9kXtV87fmECYkxRt37-uwQPZy"}
{"link": "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=DR1uBZHMKGpcNLY44gKm_JIADKwQHr1aoh8QrfMP7P9IkRlQt2Ad10KtzkvvZS3VkSMA68oVDY2OpHysBNw3EumkLInsYB1JMpK55TzK7WW"}
{"link": "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=GR0tRhMRUQ8KpMIuK0oGzgujA8SglIkt9H7C9A1bc-Wlm8yxhdoGQ7ssdxGwvlK71xCFVBb9EQtDqtXU1aUUz_"}
```

Thank you for any help.